# I am an artful duck

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, knowledge

> I am an artful duck,
>   food off the ground I pluck,
>   in order I am stuck,
>   this city's air does suck.

Where do I live?

Hint:

> I am not using the most up-to-date spelling.

Comment: Kinda broad... this can refer to a lot of cities

Comment: I can see a lot of answers coming in here ....

Comment: @North yeah point taken... tried to keep it as brief as possible, but there's always the problem of introducing false positives in the process

Comment: I don't know why Donald Trump popped into my mind on reading this.

Comment: @prog_SAHIL Seems like a legit thought process. Duck -> Donald -> ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do you live in

> Beijing?

I am an artful duck

> Peking duck, originally from Beijing

Food off the ground I pluck,

> Ducks **peck** food off the ground

In order I am stuck,

> [**Pecking** order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pecking_order)

This city's air does suck.

> Beijing is known for poor air quality

Comment: Oooh this was my second guess, I was debating between this and mine...good luck! :D (+1)

Comment: @jafe I've edited my answer, what do you think? :)

Comment: @casey, maybe the third line refers to ROT13(Orvwvatf ybat genssvp wnzf)

Comment: Answer's correct, but you're missing the wordplay :)

Comment: Could it be stuck as in rot13(fghpx va gur bira)?

Comment: rot3(Gurer'f n jbeq gung svgf yvarf 2-3 naq fbhaqf yvxr "Crxvat")

Comment: @jafe Rot13 => vf vg cvpxvat? Vafgrnq bs cyhpx vf vg cvpx fb gung gur arkg "va" cynlf jvgu vg gb znxr cvpxva juvpu fbhaqf yvxr crxvat?

Comment: @R.D very close

Comment: Hmmm. I gave it a try

Comment: @jafe I've revised my answer :)

Comment: @casey ding ding ding, we have a winner! :P

Answer (score 4):

Do you live in

> New York City?

I am an artful duck,

> A pigeon (*they prefer rock dove*).

food off the ground I pluck,

> And there's a lot on the ground in NYC and pigeons everywhere.

in order I am stuck,

> Stuck in traffic, stuck in the concrete jungle...?

this city's air does suck.

> Although not as bad as some places, NYC doesn't have the best air quality.

Comment: Flip, you beat me to it :( Tears and sadness and a +1

Comment: Close one, don't think I beat you by much!

Comment: Time to binge eat animal crackers and watch The Notebook ....

Comment: That's too far.....when I first watched it, I thought it was a rom-com.....tl;dr it was _not_ :'((

Answer (score 3):

Credits to Casey's answer and the comments that followed. I just integrated the answer. So tell me if I shouldn't do this :)

The answer is

> Peking

I am an artful duck,

> Yes Peking duck is a dish from Peking ( Now known as Beijing)

food off the ground I pluck,

> Ducks do feed off the ground "Plucking" food off it.

in order I am stuck,

> Credit to prog_sahil and casey again. This refers to the traffic jams in beijing which are well known.

this city's air does suck.

> Air pollution, lots of smog and so on.

And finally the hint

> Peking was formally romanized as Peking. The hint does say that it does not use the most up-to date spelling. The old Kanji read Peking and the new kanji reads beijing so technically it's an old spelling of the same name

Comment: It also matches the wordplay!

Comment: This was very close as well!

Comment: Oof! So close!! Oh well, will do better next time